# I don't understand narimashita in "osewa ni narimashita"

Tags: meaning

I understand that this phrase translates to.

> I have received your assistance

or

> Thanks for the help.

But I thought narimashita is the past tense of "to become"?

Is their an alternative definition I can't find or does the literal translation mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お[世話]{せわ} itself means "help, aid, assistance".

You are correct that なる means "to become".

"I have received your assistance." is a good **non-literal** translation, but **literal** translation would be "(Something) became help/aid/assistance." (i.e. "Your actions for me became help/aid/assistance.").

Comment: But when you say `Xが（お）世話になる`, this X is not what *becomes* help. Rather, it’s what *becomes* the object of someone’s help.

Comment: @aguijonazo Maybe interpretation is context-dependent? Can double-が be used to specify both subject and object? E.g. 「彼**が**彼女**が**お世話になりました。」 == 「彼**が**彼女**の**お世話になりました。」 ~= "He helped her."?

Comment: No, that interpretation is not possible.